SharePoint ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: 'Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.'
i cannot load Web from SPO using Context.ExecuteQueryAsync, i receive alayws the same error
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'
Property DisableCustomAppAuthentication is False
I used all type of connection like token.... and with ClientId+ClientSecret.
I use this Application Permission in APP: Sites.FullControl.All
using (var clientContext = new PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))
{
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, p => p.Title);
await clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();
Console.WriteLine(clientContext.Web.Title);
};

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
